# hosting acounts for large uploads

Tags: upload, hosting, large-files

im wondering if anyone knows of any host providers ( uk preferably ) that deals mostly with accepting large file uploads. Most hosts only let you push something like 1.5mb ( thats taking into account the connection and the max execution time ). What i am looking for is a host specificaly for storing files on.

I was going to create an upload script onto my application which posted the file to the external host and then return back ( using headers so the user doen't even know they have left ).

Does anyone know of a host for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a account with someone like amazon S3, they will allow files of any size and charge you based on data transfer and data strorage.